# Difficulties with .get in Python tkinter button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I`ve been working on a simple GUI and trying to receive input data thought text boxes. And then upon button being presses that data (width, height and length) would be calculated and displayed in a label.

This is just the volume calculation section of the program that I`m having issues with, no calculations involved yet, I`m just trying to .get the input data to print and make sure it works, and having been able to get it working. I must be missing something minimal.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

windowGUI = Tk()
""" ---------------Volume Calculator---------------- """

labelWidth = Label(windowGUI, text='Width').grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=W)
labelHeight = Label(windowGUI, text='Height').grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
labelLength = Label(windowGUI, text='Length').grid(row=0,column=5,sticky=W)

calcWidth = Entry(windowGUI).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=W)
calcHeight = Entry(windowGUI).grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=W)
calcLength = Entry(windowGUI).grid(row=1,column=5,sticky=W)

def calculate():
   print (calcWidth.get(), calcHeight.get(), calcLength.get())

calcButt = Button(windowGUI, text='Calculate', command=calculate)
calcButt.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W,pady=4)

windowGUI.mainloop()
```

The error I receive is the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'"

This is my first experience with tkinter on python, help/suggestions would be much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
calcWidth = Entry(windowGUI).grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=W)
```

On this line, you're saying "Create an entry, then call `grid` on it. Assign the result of the `grid` call to `calcWidth`." This is a problem because the result of `grid` is always `None`. You should do assignment and gridding on separate lines.

```
calcWidth = Entry(windowGUI)
calcWidth.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=W)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *

windowGUI = Tk()
""" ---------------Volume Calculator---------------- """

labelWidth = Label(windowGUI, text='Width').grid(row=0,column=3,sticky=W)
labelHeight = Label(windowGUI, text='Height').grid(row=0,column=4,sticky=W)
labelLength = Label(windowGUI, text='Length').grid(row=0,column=5,sticky=W)

calcWidth = Entry(windowGUI)
calcWidth.grid(row=1,column=3,sticky=W)
calcHeight = Entry(windowGUI)
calcHeight.grid(row=1,column=4,sticky=W)
calcLength = Entry(windowGUI)
calcLength.grid(row=1,column=5,sticky=W)

def calculate():
    print (calcWidth.get(), calcHeight.get(), calcLength.get())

calcButt = Button(windowGUI, text='Calculate', command=calculate)
calcButt.grid(row=3,column=4,sticky=W,pady=4)

windowGUI.mainloop()
```

[Note]: 
Also in your code you wrote "from tkinter import ttk". Remove this line, this line is unnecessary and generate error.